# Dividing data and putting into two boxplot

Tags: r, statistics, storage, boxplot

```
> sleep
extra group ID
1    0.7     1  1
2   -1.6     1  2
3   -0.2     1  3
4   -1.2     1  4
5   -0.1     1  5
6    3.4     1  6
7    3.7     1  7
8    0.8     1  8
9    0.0     1  9
10   2.0     1 10
11   1.9     2  1
12   0.8     2  2
13   1.1     2  3
14   0.1     2  4
15  -0.1     2  5
16   4.4     2  6
17   5.5     2  7
18   1.6     2  8
19   4.6     2  9
20   3.4     2 10
```

I have this set of Data and Im supposed to Divide it by the effects that GROUP have on different people and put it into two different boxplot but as you can see theres group 1 and group 2 and they are on the same data which is group so I dont know how to divede the data into group 1 and group 2 can u help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to divide the data to put it into a boxplot:

```
boxplot(extra~group,data=sleep)
```

[image]

You can explore the different options available by using `?boxplot`.

Some people like to use the `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sleep,aes(x=group,y=extra,group=group))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Others prefer `lattice`:

```
bwplot(group~extra,data=sleep)
```

[image]

Comment: That makes lot of sense and its simpler that what I thought I was trying things like boxplot(extra(group==1)) hahah Thanks a million thou!

Comment: Would it work same for Histograms and scaterplots? Like  hist(extra~group, data=sleep, breaks=5)??? SOrry for bothering xD

Comment: It doesn't work for `hist()`, but you can do `ggplot(sleep,aes(x=extra,fill=as.factor(group)))+geom_histogram(position="identity",alpha=0.5)` or `ggplot(sleep,aes(x=extra))+geom_histogram()+facet_grid(~group)`. For a scatter plot you can do `plot(sleep[,1:2])` or `ggplot(sleep,aes(x=group,y=extra))+geom_point()`

Comment: It says Error: could not find function "ggplot" and for the scatter plot is showing only one scatter plot not the two of them! Im supposed to have to graph for each one for Durg1 and one for drung 2 :(

Comment: `install.packages("ggplot2")` then `library(ggplot2)`.

Comment: I wont be able to Install anything on my computer lab to do this exercises.. is there not way without it? Sorry i know im asking a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good dataset to use `ggplot2` with.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sleep, aes(x=factor(group), y=extra)) + geom_boxplot()
```